# How can we prove that $\frac{a}{b }\times\frac{c}{d} =\frac{ac}{bd}$

Tags: calculus, self-learning

I am slowly reading **calculus** by michael spivak and it is one of the problems in first chapter.
however I cant prove it please help me with it...

Comment: i apologize for asking incorrect question firstbut now i have edited it.

Answer (score 3):

To see that equality holds, we will write the elements $\frac1b$ and $\frac1d$ as $b^{-1}$ and $d^{-1}$, respectively. Thus

\begin{align*}
\frac ab\cdot\frac cd&=(a\cdot b^{-1})\cdot(c\cdot d^{-1})\\
&=(a\cdot c)\cdot(b^{-1}\cdot d^{-1})\\
&=(a\cdot c)\cdot(b\cdot d)^{-1}\\
&=\frac{ac}{bd}.
\end{align*}

The second line uses the associative and commutative properties of multiplication.

Comment: I want  to ask that how could you establish the associative property for multiplying the fractions , without using the equality I have asked.you can establish it for non fractions but for using that for fractions i think that one would have to depend on the equality.....

Comment: @HiteshPathak, the fraction notation is just shorthand and doesn't derive from any of the axioms. So, what $\frac ab$ is really saying is $a\cdot b^{-1}$. Since $a$ and $b^{-1}$ are in the same field, we can commute them. Is that better?

Comment: If we truly are going back to just the field axioms, then I'd argue that $b^{-1}d^{-1}=(bc)^{-1}$ also needs to be proven; however, it is unclear what OP is asking for here

Answer (score 0):

Proving something like this, something that many people are often taught as the definition of multiplying fractions, is a difficult task because you need to first take the step of specifying exactly what you know and are assuming, separating the definitions from the things you don't want to assume.

Let us take as a given that $a/b=a \cdot \frac{1}{b}$, so that we can convert the problem to something only involving recipricals and multiplication, namely,

$$ a \cdot c \cdot \frac{1}{b}\cdot \frac{1}{d} = ac \frac{1}{bd}. $$

Since, given any equation, we can always multiply both sides by ac, it suffices to show that

$$ \frac{1}{b} \cdot \frac{1}{d}=\frac{1}{bd}.$$

We can do this by multiplying both sides by $bd$ (and using the fact that, by definition, $x \frac{1}{x}=1$ for all nonzero $x$) and rearranging, using the fact that multiplication is commutative.

Explicitly,

$$1=\left(b\cdot \frac{1}{b}\right)\left(d\cdot \frac{1}{d}\right)=bd\frac{1}{b}\frac{1}{d}$$

and so dividing both sides by $bd$ (or multiplying both sides by $1/bd$), we get

$$ \left(\frac{1}{b}\cdot \frac{1}{d}\right)=\frac{1}{bd}$$.

But for the above to be considered a proof, you have to accept that $a/b=a \frac{1}{b}$ and $b\frac{1}{b}=b/b=1$.  If you do not accept that as a starting point, what I have done is not enough.

Comment: I could not understand how you proved that  1/b . 1/d = 1/bd , I can assume that a.1/b = a/b

Comment: @HiteshPathak Were you okay with the logic that $1=bd(1/b)(1/d)$?  That was just using the fact that multiplication is commutative (in other words, that the order you multiply things in doesn't matter).  From there we just divided both sides by bd, which cancels the bd out from in front of the right hand side.

Comment: I think that you are using associativity of multiplication but how would you establish this property for fractions , clearly what does 1/b.1/d mean , adding a fraction a fractional number of times I cant just get that..

Comment: Associativity says we don't need to use parentheses, but I was reordering things, so I had to use commutativity too.  Regardless, $1/b$ and $1/d$ are just numbers.  They are defined by their relationship to $b$ and $d$ respectively, but associativity and communtativity of multiplication holds for all numbers.  Of course, depending on where you are coming from, this needs to be proven.  If you are just given the rational numbers or the real numbers or the complex numbers, that is one thing.  If you are starting from the integers and constructing the rationals, there is work to do.